# How to create my own PageSize variable to create a PDF document using iTextpdf

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, itext7

I want to create a pdf document using iTextpdf 7 but I don't want to use any of the default page sizes.

I want to set the width and height of my paper size but when I try to do it using `Rectangle()` class, it shows me errors and I can not create anything. 
I've never used this library before and I don't know how to do it well.

This is an example of the code I made:

```
   String url_file= "C:\\Users\\Mike89\\Documents\\PDFJava\\pdfFiles\\SALES\\SALEINVOICE"+id+".pdf";

 PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(url_file);
 PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);            
 Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(148, 350);
 Document document = new Document(pdf, pagesize);
 document.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);

         Table table1 = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(1)).useAllAvailableWidth().setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    Cell cell1;
    cell1 = new Cell();
    cell1.add(new Paragraph("COMPANY NAME").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(5).setBold()).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    cell1.add(new Paragraph("DOCUMENT ID").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(5)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    cell1.add(new Paragraph("COMPANY ADDRESS").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(5)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    cell1.add(new Paragraph("TELEPHONE").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(5)).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    table1.addCell(cell1);
    document.add(table1);

   document.close();
```

The error that netbeans shows me this:

```
 incompatible types: Rectangle cannot be converted to PageSize
```

I don't want to use PageSize.A8 or A9 or A10 or anything like that. I just want to create my own page size, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangle and PageSize are different types, although PageSize extends Rectangle, but the Document constructor expects a PageSize. In Netbeans, use CTRL-SPACE to see more while working:
[image]

Please replace this

```
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(148, 350);
Document document = new Document(pdf, pagesize);
```

with this:

```
PageSize pagesize = new PageSize(148, 350);
Document document = new Document(pdf, pagesize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the changes your submitted in this answer and it's not showing error, the pdf is created but when I try to open it AdobeReader displays an error like "The file is broken or Damaged" and the size of the file is 0 bytes.

Comment: This could mean that the file already exists due to the previous problems. Delete it and try again and watch for any messages on the console. I just managed to create the file.

Comment: Actual code I used: https://pastebin.com/zfvbZKh2 (this contains also the imports)

Comment: Yesm perfect. That works for me now. I did Delete the existing files and tried one more time and the problem was solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, the need to delete the existing files might indicate you do something wrong when saving the pdf, e.g. appending to existing files...